# create type that has all properties of interface A and interface B

Tags: typescript

I want `myValue` to be of type `interface A` or `interface B`

```
interface interfaceA {
  commonProp: any;
  specificToA: any;
}

interface interfaceB {
  commonProp: any;
  specificToB: any;
}


let myValue: interfaceA | interfaceB;

myValue.interfaceA // doesn't work, I only have access to commonProp
```

How can I have `myValue` have access to `specificToA` and `specificToB` ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [type guards](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-book/blob/master/docs/types/typeGuard.md).

```
function isA(arg: any): arg is interfaceA
{
    return 'specificToA' in arg;
}

if (isA(myValue))
{// Here typescript will know you are dealing with interfaceA
    let v = myValue.specificToA;
}
```